# Degguging bottle does not work

Tags: python, bottle

I cannot debug bottle.  I have 500 errors in dev.  I am using the latest bottle wit the `debug=True` flag.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Interactive mode
    run(host='localhost', port=8049,debug=True)
```

This is what I get.....

```
Bottle v0.11.rc1 server starting up (using WSGIRefServer())...
Listening on http://localhost:8049/
Hit Ctrl-C to quit.

localhost - - [30/Sep/2012 18:59:13] "POST /bidder/ HTTP/1.1" 500 1407
localhost - - [30/Sep/2012 18:59:14] "POST /bidder/ HTTP/1.1" 500 1407
localhost - - [30/Sep/2012 18:59:14] "POST /bidder/ HTTP/1.1" 500 1407
localhost - - [30/Sep/2012 18:59:15] "POST /bidder/ HTTP/1.1" 500 1407
localhost - - [30/Sep/2012 18:59:15] "POST /bidder/ HTTP/1.1" 500 1407
```

I don't mind the 500 as long I can find out why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `debug=False` keyword parameter in the `run()` function is only available in the current development version; the current 0.10.x code itself *ignores* doesn't yet support it.

Instead, use the [`debug()` function](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/api.html#bottle.debug) instead:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Interactive mode
    run(host='localhost', port=8049)
    debug(True)
```

or run with the `--debug` command-line flag.

You may have to import the `debug` function from `bottle` if you haven't done so already. The tutorial explains [debug mode in more detail](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial.html#tutorial-debugging).

Comment: Using debug(True) did work.  Using run(host='localhost', port=8049,debug=True)
 per the docs did not work.  Thanks